# How to prefix post permalinks with /blog/ - without affecting custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have several custom post types, which are properly structured as `/%post_type%/%postname%/`, however I wish to have the same effect for regular blog entries: `/blog/%postname%/`

If I prepend the permalink structure with `/blog/` it affects the custom post types as well, so currently my permalink structure is simply `/%postname%/`

Which is the recommended way of doing this? I had a solution involving some rewrites, but the permalink shown in the post editor area does not reflect it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the `'with_front'` parameter for the post type’s slug to `FALSE`:

```
'rewrite'    => array (
    'slug'       => 'posttypeslug',
    'with_front' => FALSE
),
```