# "set_front" => false on custom post type breaks wp_list_categories links

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

My question is related to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55522/how-to-prefix-post-permalinks-with-blog-without-affecting-custom-post-types). I would like my post permalinks to be prefixed by `/blog/`, but I don't want this prefix to be applied to my custom post type *portfolio*. In other words, I expect post links to use `/blog/` and portfolio links to use `/portfolio/`. This is why I set `set_front` to `false` for this post type and set my permalink structure to `/blog/%postname%/`.

This almost works, except that a `wp_list_categories` call in my page header prints broken links. My skill taxonomy links have the form `/portfolio/[SKILLNAME]`, but this function is outputting `/blog/portfolio/[SKILLNAME]`, which leads to a 404 page.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here? I already tried clicking *Save changes* on the Permalinks settings page to force a flush of the rewrite rules.

Comment: Can you post your code? Do you mean `with_front` instead of `set_front`?

Comment: Aw shoot... I'm an idiot and I've been staring at code for too long. Thanks :) Should I delete this question?

Comment: I answered the question to keep things neat. Voting to close as "too localized"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you are using is wrong. There is no `set_front` parameter when you [register a Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). The appropriate parameter is `with_front`.

> 'with_front' => bool Should the permastruct be prepended with the
>   front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your
>   links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to true
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments